Swiper React - Different Heights Scroll Issue
I use Swiper component from swiper/react library. I have two slides, with different heights. I set autoHeight so slider wrapper adapts its height to the height of the currently active slide.
Now, I have a requirement to scrollIntoView a div that exists in one of the slides - the one with the smaller height. When the scroll happens, swiper elements lose composition.
.swiper-wrapper div has the correct height, but it isn't displayed inside the .swiper div.
You can see here the height difference that is created between the tabs after the scroll:

